# Dynamic Product Comparison Page

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm working on creating a product comparison page for a website and am looking for a direction to take. Essentially what will happen is a the page will receive 2-4 product IDs in the query string (delimited in some way) and then build the comparison page.

Now this would be easy if I just needed to databind down the page with each product being a horizontal line item. However I need to make them vertical line items so they can be compared side by side. I also need this to be a single page that does it dynamically rather than 3 separate pages that I redirect to and manually set everything in.

Is there an easy way to do something like this? Like is there a way I can rotate a listview or something in order to get it to display a single row vertically rather than horizontally?

Or should I rotate my data so that I can still bind normally but lose readability?

Any direction would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You could pivot your data: http://michaeljswart.com/2011/06/forget-about-pivot/ Just one link I found that seemed pretty helpful.